# Is the New Gods character of Seagrin ever explored beyond his first appearance, when he's already dead?

Tags: dc

The beginning of *New Gods #4*, the protagonist Orion recovers the corpse of a dead New God named Seagrin and returns him to the source.  I know that Jack Kirby never wrote drew any more appearances by this character, but I was wondering if some other writer might have provided more backstory for this character.

A little bit about Seagrin can be inferred from his original appearance.  His name and outfit suggest that he was fighting the Deep Six from Apokalips when he was killed.  Orion also describes him as a "gentle warrior."  I just thought it might neat to know more about an aquatic New God character.